# How to mute/unmute all in discord voice channel for discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that mutes everyone currently in a voice channel by adding a role "TempMute" to them. Then when I send /unmuteAll I would like everyone who has the "TempMute" tag to have the tag removed. I have tried several different ways with no success. I am using discord.js version 12.2.0.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');


voiceChatChannelId="123456789"

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    var vc = bot.channels.cache.get(voiceChatChannelId);

    if (message.content == '/muteAll') {
        for (let member of vc.members){
            //add members all to "TempMute" role
        }
    }

    else if (message.content == '/unmuteAll') {
        for (let member of vc.members){
            //remove ALL members from role "TempMute"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) you can use [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)[`.add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) or [`GuildMember.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)[`.remove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) methods to either add or remove a role.

---

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    var vc = bot.channels.cache.get(voiceChatChannelId);

    if (message.content == '/muteAll') {
        for (let member of vc.members.array()){
            //add members all to "TempMute" role
             member.roles.add("RoleID")
        }
    }

    else if (message.content == '/unmuteAll') {
        for (let member of vc.members.array()){
            //remove ALL members from role "TempMute"
             member.roles.remove("RoleID")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined". I (the server owner) as well as another account (used as a test acc with no special admin privileges) are in the voice channel.

Comment: Try to `console.log(member)` and `console.log(member.roles)`. Are any of these undefined?

Comment: console.log(member.roles) is undefined, console.log(member) prints all the json information for each user.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to loop through a `Collection` without transforming it to an `Array` first (or you can just use `Collection#forEach` instead). Check my updated code.